# Clicar no botão Seguir do Instagram com Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, instagram-api

Gostaria de saber como apertar o botão de seguir do Instagram com o Selenium, já tentei de varias formas e nenhuma eu consigo apertar. Sempre fala ou que o element não é clicavel ou  não consegue encontrar o elemento.

```
<span class="vBF20 _1OSdk"><button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX  _6VtSN  
yZn4P   ">Seguir</button></span>
```

Esse é o código do botão que quero clicar. Ja testei das seguintes maneiras.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button")).click()
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("_5f5mN jIbKX _6VtSN yZn4P")).Click()
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByClassName('_5f5mN jIbKX _6VtSN yZn4P')[0].click()");
```

Já não sei mais oq tentar ... alguém sabe como fazer ? ...

OBS: Esse ultimo funciona no navegador se eu jogar no console. Mas quando tento pelo Selenium ele não encontra o Elemento para clicar.

OBS: Testei os seguintes códigos abaixo e também não funcionaram

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1].click()");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("\\button:text()="Seguir"[1]")).Click();
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.evaluate(\"//button[text()='Seguir'][1]\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()");
```

Comment: tenta trocar o xpath por //button[text()='Seguir'][1] , esse css ai tá com cara de que é nomeado dinamicamente

Comment: Pergunta, é para teste ou para bot?

Comment: Estou testando e ao mesmo tempo fazendo um bot tambem. Lucas, vou testar aqui e falo se funcionou.

Comment: Lucas Miranda, infelizmente não funcionou o metodo que passou com xpath. https://prnt.sc/uu8i7n

Comment: uma tentativa nova, tenta usar o script executor pra rodar isso aqui document.evaluate("//button[text()='Seguir'][1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()

Comment: Vou testar e te dou retorno

Comment: Infelizmente deu erro  - https://prnt.sc/uubv4s

Comment: ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.evaluate(\"//button[text()='Seguir'][1]\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()");

esse o codigo .. parece que o Instagram nao deixa rodar pelo bot .. pq pelo console no navegador deu certo...

Answer (score 1):

Muda de classe para um xpath que com certeza irá funcionar. Exemplo:

```
IWebDriver webdriver = WebDriverFactory.CreateWebDriver(Browser.Chrome, @"ChromeDriver", true);

webdriver.LoadPage(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), @"https://www.instagram.com/neymarjr/"); //entra no perfil 

IWebElement BtnSeguir = null;
BtnSeguir = webdriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/span/span[1]/button")); 
BtnSeguir.Click(); //clica pra seguir
```